# Using ArcGIS Pro Explore tool?

Tags: sql-server, arcgis-pro, identify

I'm experimenting with this new ArcGIS Pro 2.0+ that became available at my workplace (currently using ArcMap), and I'm experiencing some inconsistencies with datasets brought in via query layers from our SQL Server (currently '08 server. Tried w/ a '16 server and had same issues).

Some datasets seem to work just fine (selecting / "identifying" / searching), and some datasets erroneously return incorrect records when I "identify" them with the new "Explore" button. Example: I "identify" a utility pole in front of our building, which I know has a name of "POLE-X", but the "identify/explore" window returns back "POLE-W". If I "identify" that pole again it may return another pole, "POLE-Z", or sometimes no object attributes at all.

Has anybody encountered odd behavior like this before?

[image]

Comment: Another note, I thought since our datasets are refreshed every morning it could be a caching issue; that my computer was mis-reading the cache or seeing it as out of order. I set the Cache settings to "Don't cache any data locally" for the layer, but the issue persists so this does not seem to be the issue...

Comment: We also are experiencing this same behavior using ArcGIS Pro 2.13 and spatial views Oracle 11g registered with the geodatabase. Some views work fine, but others do not. There doesn't seem to be a pattern. @moore2ax, were you able to resolve this or learn anything more about it?

Answer (score 3):

There may be multiple points coincident.  The order of features coming back from the database isn't deterministic, so if you have two points on top of each other you could get multiple results clicking on them.

Comment: We do have coincident data we plot from our database, but not in this table. There is only 1 object at that location I am referencing above. I will click on a result I know to exist in my local area, and the "explore/identify" window will return a result in a state hundreds of miles away...